# FFmpeg не заданное время при записи видео

Tags: ffmpeg

Если запустить `ffmpeg` для записи видео из какого-нибудь источника, который так же постоянно запущен и никогда не отключается.
Через некоторое время, мы закрываем запись видео с помощью `q`.
Что будет с видео, запишется оно или нет?
Или как правильно завершить запись видео, у которого нет точного времени записи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё будет нормально. `q` отрабатывается корректно, файл финализируется (будет вызван `writeTrailer()`). Выведется статистика по записанным байтам.

Да, если это будет не так, то это повод создать Bug-report разработчикам на http://ffmpeg.org